# Show Firefox bookmarks button in Firefox navigation bar?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I tested Natty Beta 2 yesterday and found that the bookmarks button is hidden. The usual way to show it seems to be hiding the menubar under Customize, however there is no Menubar option in there now. Is there a way to show the bookmarks button?

I can download Firefox from Mozilla and use that version but that's not the best option.

Comment: I was using Firefox 4 on Maverick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly disable the global menu extension to regain your bookmarks button. However, I wouldn't recommend this as the menu bar essentially recreates the bookmarks button without taking up any space.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can put this code into your [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css) file:

```
#bookmarks-menu-button-container {display:-moz-box!important;}
```

In Firefox 23 and newer, the following may work instead:

```
#bookmarks-menu-button {display:-moz-box!important;}
```

The button will show up in her place and you don't have to disable the global menu extension.

You can always check for correct CSS selector by navigating to `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` and using Firefox's Inspector in Developer Tools.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I think. The accepted answer is only a work-around with quite heavy side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the bookmarks button to another toolbar, like the add-ons bar or bookmarks bar, then it will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is correct, but you can also pop it into your tab toolbar if you don't use a bookmark bar etc, which is what I did.